# Parse an xml file depending on the current language

Tags: android

Is there a way to parse an xml file depending on the current language? For example, I have two countries.xml files. One in the values folder, and another one in the values-de folder. I want to parse the file specific to the current language.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html

Answer (score 0):

The android environment parses these files for you, and you can get to the data through various accessors, like if you have a set of strings in your strings.xml, you use

```
getText(R.strings.my_string);
```

which will give you the string from the strings.xml for that locale (or the default one if none match).

Check the [developer's guide on resource localization](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) for more info.